# Issue while initialising db in airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I am new to airflow and trying to initiate a MySQL db to airflow. I have created a virtual environment and installed the respective packages. I am getting the following error :

airflow initdb

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//Documents/Test/venv/bin/airflow", line 23, in 
    import argcomplete
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'

I have installed the necessary packages, specifically pip3 install argcomplete which shows the output as :

Requirement already satisfied: argcomplete in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.23; python_version == "3.7" in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from argcomplete) (1.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.23; python_version == "3.7"->argcomplete) (3.1.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install the library **mysql-conector** with pip as follows:

```
pip3 install mysql-connector
```

or,

```
pip install mysql-connector
```

Once installed, try running the command to initialize AirflowDB

Update:

Create a user and database in MySQL for Airflow, and pass the user and its password to airflow in its **airflow.cfg**. Use the following steps for user creation on MySQL db.

```
CREATE USER 'airfow'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'airflow123*'; 

CREATE DATABASE airflowdb; 

GRANT ALL ON airflowdb.* to 'airflow'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'airflow123*'; 

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now in your **airflow.cfg**, pass the username,, password and database
name that you have used in the above steps and try to perform the `initdb` command from the **`AIRFLOW_HOME`** directory again.

NOTE: To create a user and database, you have to log into the database as a root user

Comment: I did that : pip3 install mysql-connector, but still getting the same error

Comment: can you connect to the Mysql Database from the machine where you aretrying to run the initdb command?

Comment: yes, I am able to connect, create a new schema, create a table, etc I am using MySQL workbench to connect to MySQL.

Comment: Can you share teh Airflow Environment configuration file in your question. In our deployments we install **PyMySQL** along with **mysql-connector**

Comment: is it the airflow.cfg file you are talking about? or pyvenv.cfg?

Comment: the airflow.cfg

Comment: any specific parameters to check?? it's quite a huge file, I am not sure I can paste it in this thread

Comment: Can you try to install PyMySQL on the same node alongside mysql-connector and try the process again? Also which **Airflow Executor** are you using? Also are you running the command from the directory containing the **airflow.cfg** file?

Comment: I am using CeleryExecutor. The airflow.cfg is in the directory : /Users/<my local folder>/airflow  I have created a virtual environment and trying to initialise db from the virtual env in this folder : /Users/<my local folder>/Documents/Test/venv

Comment: You have to run the `**airflow iinitdb**` command from the Directory that is your AIRFLOW_HOME. This directory should contain the **airflow.cfg**, which the airflow executable uses to create the required tables in MySQL(in your case)

Comment: I tried it from AIRFLOW_HOME as well, but I am getting the same error

Comment: I have updated my answer above, could you look at that

Comment: sql_alchemy_conn should be updated in airflow.cfg right?

Comment: Yes the SQLAlchemy string in the CFG fir would have to be updated

Comment: Nope, that didn't help, I am still getting the same error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<mylocalfolder>/Documents/Test/venv/bin/airflow", line 23, in <module>
    import argcomplete
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'

Comment: Can you try installing Airflow on your user as opposed to installing it in a VENV? The steps i shared with you should have sufficed the installation requirements.

Comment: can you accept the answer if the solution worked for you?

Comment: If I install it in my user, I get the following error : ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Do you have a Vanilla Python installation? or is it Anaconda/Miniconda?

Comment: Anaconda python installation

Comment: then install pymysql and mysql-connector in your Anaconda installation as follows: `conda install pymysql`, `conda install mysql-connector` and then proceed with your airflow installation

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it, it should solve the problem.